# how to run django sslserver(https) such that remote systems in network can also access?

Tags: python, django, ubuntu, ssl, https

I am trying to run my server with https, so I installed `django-sslserver`, and running as below.

```
python manage.py runsslserver --certificate /etc/ssl/certs/server.crt --key /etc/ssl/private/server.key 0.0.0.0:8000
```

It is running successfully with above command. I am able to access through `localhost:8000` or `127.0.0.1:8000`, but not able to access through `192.168.2.13:8000` here `192.168.2.13` is my IP address.

**Why I am not able to access through my IP address ?**

And even If start the server with other than `8000` port, it is default taking as `8000`. Here in the below example I have used `8014`, But its taking `8000` as default.

```
root@nagapavan-HP-ProBook-440-G2:/home/nagapavan/Downloads/celestial_NAS# python manage.py runsslserver --certificate /etc/ssl/certs/server.c --key /etc/ssl/private/server.key 127.0.0.1:8014
Validating models...
System check identified some issues:

WARNINGS:
NAS.UserProfile.user: (fields.W342) Setting unique=True on a ForeignKey has the same effect as using a OneToOneField.
    HINT: ForeignKey(unique=True) is usually better served by a OneToOneField.
System check identified 1 issue (0 silenced).
October 06, 2015 - 13:21:40
Django version 1.8.4, using settings 'celestial_NAS.settings'
Starting development server at 127.0.0.1:8000/
Using SSL certificate: /etc/ssl/certs/server.crt
Using SSL key: /etc/ssl/private/server.key
Quit the server with CONTROL-C
```

**Why it is taking the port number 8000 as default?**

I found one more command to start server as below. I can give the IP address and port number. It is working as as expected. But I am able to access with the IP address but not able to access through `localhost:9000` or `127.0.0.1:9000` even I am accessing the server my local system itself.

**What might be the reason for above statement?**

And even I am able to access through my IP address with `https://192.168.2.13:9000`, I am not able to access the server from remote system which is in the same network(even pingable to each other)

**Why I am not able to access the server from remote system in the same network, Do we need to do any configuration file changes?**

```
python manage.py runsslserver --certificate /etc/ssl/certs/server.c --key /etc/ssl/private/server.key --addrport 192.168.2.13:9000
```

**Note:** All the URIs above accessed with **https**

Adding the error which I am getting while starting sslserver as below:

Is it the reason of issues above?

```
----------------------------------------
----------------------------------------
Exception happened during processing of request from ('192.168.1.166', 56694)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/SocketServer.py", line 295, in _handle_request_noblock
    self.process_request(request, client_address)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/SocketServer.py", line 321, in process_request
    self.finish_request(request, client_address)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/SocketServer.py", line 334, in finish_request
    self.RequestHandlerClass(request, client_address, self)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/servers/basehttp.py", line 102, in __init__
    super(WSGIRequestHandler, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/SocketServer.py", line 649, in __init__
    self.handle()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/servers/basehttp.py", line 167, in handle
    self.raw_requestline = self.rfile.readline(65537)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/socket.py", line 476, in readline
    data = self._sock.recv(self._rbufsize)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/ssl.py", line 341, in recv
    return self.read(buflen)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/ssl.py", line 260, in read
    return self._sslobj.read(len)
SSLError: [Errno 1] _ssl.c:1429: error:14094418:SSL routines:SSL3_READ_BYTES:tlsv1 alert unknown ca
----------------------------------------
----------------------------------------
```

Comment: Have you checked your firewall setting on the server where you running the django app? Is the port 9000 (or whichever you use for the app) open? Is there any intermediate network hardware between the server and the computere from where you want to access the app? If yes, then check these devices if they let connections via port 9000 pass.

Comment: Hi, Here starting the server with http is working with any port even 9000, but the issue I am facing only when server running with https(runsslserver)...

Answer (score -1):

Its working kindly use instead of 0.0.0.0 try your network ip,and allow on host add network ip

Comment: Have you tried this yourself with this exact problem?  Your suggestion shouldn't help, as specifying `0.0.0.0`, which is what the OP is doing, means "listen on all interfaces", including the host's NIC card as well as the loopback interface.  Specifying the host IP will simply cause the code to not listen on the loopback, causing `localhost` and `127.0.0.1` to stop working.